# Selecting unique records from sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, unique, distinct, sql

I have an sqlite table called Tracks with information about lots of tracks stored in my music library. The columns in the table are as follows: `artistName`, `trackName`, `trackPath`, `imagePath`, `year`, `albumName`, `bpm`, `genre1`, `genre2`, `genre3`.

I use a simple select statement to return all unique tracks in my table, for example to get all tracks that are in the Rock genre i use the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT artistName, trackName, trackPath, imagePath, year, albumName, bpm, genre1, genre2, genre3
FROM Tracks
WHERE genre1='Rock' or genre2='Rock' or genre3='Rock'
```

The problem I have is that I don't want to return 2 records for a track that may have a different year value but the same artistName, trackName, albumName. For example if I have 2 tracks both with `artistName = 'Bruce Springsteen'` and `trackName = 'Dancing In The Dark'` and `albumName = 'Greatest Hits'` but the years may be different, one may be `year = '1984'` and the other may be `year = '1985'`, I just want to return one of these and not both.

Can any one please help me out on this one? It's driving me crazy?!

Comment: Add `limit 1` to the end of your query? Besides you should create a new table called `track_genres` to attach the genres to your tracks to avoid `genre123` columns.

Answer (score 2):

You could use what you have but add aggregation to your query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT artistName, trackName, trackPath, imagePath, MAX(year), albumName, bpm, genre1, genre2, genre3 
FROM Tracks 
where genre1='Rock' or genre2='Rock' or genre3='Rock' 
group by artistName, trackName, trackPath, imagePath, albumName, bpm, genre1, genre2, genre3
```

The result will be one record but the year will be the latest year.